# Merging two vectors at random in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors x and y. x is a larger vector compared to y. For example (x is set to all zeros here, but that need not be the case)

```
x = rep(0,20)
y = c(2,3,-1,-1)
```

What I want to accomplish is overlay some y's in x but at random. So in the above example, x would look like

```
0,0,2,3,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,2,3,-1,-1,...
```

Basically, I'll step through each value in x, pull a random number, and if that random number is less than some threshold, I want to overlay y for the next 4 places in x unless I've reached the end of x. Would any of the apply functions help? Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Fist: that would not overlay the array. Roman: your solution would bloat up the original array. @Carl: I can't fully understand your approach. After some tinkering, I've reverted to using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing it would be to choose points at random (the same length as `x`) from the two vectors combined:

```
sample(c(x, y), length(x), replace = TRUE)
```

If you want to introduce some probability into it, you could do something like:

```
p <- c(rep(2, each = length(x)), rep(1, each = length(y)))
sample(c(x, y), length(x), prob = p, replace = TRUE)
```

This is saying that an `x` point is twice as likely to be chosen over a `y` point (change the 2 and 1 in `p` accordingly for different probabilities).

Comment: Does this guarantee the output vector has same length as input `x` ?

Comment: It should with `length(x)` in `sample()`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes :-) .  Write some function like

```
ranx <- runif(length(x)-length(y)+1)
# some loop or apply func...
if (ranx[j] < threshold) x[j:j+length(y)] <- y
# and make sure to stop the loop at length(y)-length(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following worked for me.

```
i = 1
while(i <= length(x)){
 p.rand = runif(1,0,1)
 if(p.rand < prob[i]){
  p[i:(i+length(y))] = y
  i = i+length(y)
 }
 i = i + 1
}
```

where prob[i] is some probability vector.